# PHP and JSON comment help

Tags: jquery, json

thanks for looking

my problem is that i cant seem to get jquery to display my generated data.

here is my JSON output

```
("posts":[{"id":"1-2","time":"0","name":"dash","avatar":"http:\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\/9ff30cc2646099e31a4ee4c0376091b0?s=182&d=identicon&r=PG","comment":"rtetretrete tet rt uh utert"},{"id":"2-2","time":"0","name":"james","avatar":"http:\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\/d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e?s=182&d=identicon&r=PG","comment":"fsdfdfsdf\r\n"}])
```

and here is my jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var url="comments.php";
        $.getJSON(url,function(json){
            $.each(json.posts,function(i,post){
$("#content").append(
    '<div class="post">'+
        '<h1>'+post.name+'</h1>'+
        '<p>'+post.comment+'</p>'+
        '<p>added: <em>'+post.time+'</em></p>'+
        '<p>posted by: <strong>'+post.name+'</strong></p>'+
        '<p>avatar: <strong>'+post.avatar+'</strong></p>'+
    '</div>'
); });      
});
    });
```

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: The json is being generated by php. The actual problem isn't related to that but it is involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just tried to validate your JSON using `http://www.jsonlint.com/`

And it failed:

```
syntax error, unexpected TINVALID, expecting '{' or '[' at line 1
Parsing failed
```

The overall (outside) brackets need to be changed from `(` and `)` to `{` and `}` This will validate your JSON and the script should work fine

Answer (score 1):

I didnt check your syntax for you json, but if it is correct then try this before sending the output (in PHP file)

```
header ('Content-type: application/json');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Json object is missing leading and trailing curly braces, thus is not valid.
Try to add them:

```
{"posts":[{"id":"1-2","time":"0","name":"dash","avatar":"http:\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\/9ff30cc2646099e31a4ee4c0376091b0?s=182&d=identicon&r=PG","comment":"rtetretrete tet rt uh utert"},{"id":"2-2","time":"0","name":"james","avatar":"http:\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\/d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e?s=182&d=identicon&r=PG","comment":"fsdfdfsdf\r\n"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

json should be

```
{
    "posts": [
        {
            "id": "1-2",
            "time": "0",
            "name": "dash",
            "avatar": "http:\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\/9ff30cc2646099e31a4ee4c0376091b0?s=182&d=identicon&r=PG",
            "comment": "rtetretrete tet rt uh utert" 
        },
        {
            "id": "2-2",
            "time": "0",
            "name": "james",
            "avatar": "http:\/\/www.gravatar.com\/avatar\/d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e?s=182&d=identicon&r=PG",
            "comment": "fsdfdfsdf\r\n" 
        }
    ]
}
```

use [jsonLint](http://www.jsonlint.com/) to validate json..